# Node.js public css files 404 not found

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm learning node.js and I have an error serving public CSS files to one URL.
It works with almost every pages, I go on the page and the css file is loaded from 127.0.0.1/css/style.css.
When the URL is 127.0.0.1/project/idProject it tries to get the css file from 127.0.0.1/project/css/style.css.

```
// INCLUDE MODULES =======================================================
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var Twig = require('twig');
var twig = Twig.twig;
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

// Assets ================================================================
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public/images/favicon.ico'))); 
// Start mongoose
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

// USER MANAGEMENT =======================================================
require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration
app.use(express.logger('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(express.cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); // to support URL-encoded bodies
app.set('view engine', 'twig'); // set up twig for templating
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash())

// ROUTES =======================================================
// Set authentication variable
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    app.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
    next();
});
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);

//ERROR MANAGEMENT =======================================================
app.use(app.router);
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.status(404);

  // respond with html page
  if (req.accepts('html')) {
    res.render('errors/404.twig', { url: req.url });
    return;
  }
  // respond with json
  if (req.accepts('json')) {
    res.send({ error: 'Not found' });
    return;
  }
  // default to plain-text. send()
  res.type('txt').send('Not found');
});
/*app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  // we may use properties of the error object
  // here and next(err) appropriately, or if
  // we possibly recovered from the error, simply next().
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('errors/500.twig', { error: err });
});*/

//SOCKET IO =======================================================
//Quand on client se connecte, on le note dans la console
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("New connection");
});

// LISTEN SERVER =======================================================
server.listen(80);
```

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Regards !

Comment: My guess is that the url to the css file in your html document is relative (`css/style.css`). Changing it to `/css/style.css`  should solve your problem. (`express.static` tries to find the file `__dirname + 'public'+'/project/css/style.css'` when the url `127.0.0.1/project/css/style.css` is requested)

Answer (score 3):

I tried approach which I saw in the comments, and because it did not work for me, I am posting an answer that worked.

All .css files are static, so you have to serve them to the client. However, you do not serve static files as a express middleware. Therefor you have to add them.

`app.use(express.static(__dirname, 'css'));`

Answer (score 0):

Hi it was a problem for me to solve this, but with the help of salvador it was posible.

The only thing that im going to put is all the code and the you make the reference in the html, you only need to put the file not the folder in the html file.

```
  //The index.js code
    var express = require('express');
    const path = require ('path');
    //app va a ser mi servidor.
    var app = express();

    app.set('port', 3000)

    //app.use(express.static('./public'));
    //app.use(express.static( 'css'));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css')));
    app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('localhost:3000')
    } );
```

[this is the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpcJt.png)